# How should I store and compute Hamming distance between binary codes?

Tags: c++, math, hash, hamming-distance

1. How can I efficiently store binary codes?  For certain fixed sizes, such as 32 bits, there are primitive types that can be used.  But what if I my binary codes are much longer?
2. What is the fastest way to compute the Hamming distance between two binary codes?

Comment: What about std::bitset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use [`std::bitset<N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), defined in the `<bitset>` header, where `N` is the number of bits (*not* bytes).
2. Compute the Hamming distance between two binary codes `a` and `b` using `(a ^ b).count()`.

Comment: I don't understand what if use 30 bit codes I still can use 32bit integer?(maybe mask 2 first bits somehow)?

Comment: @mrgloom I would use this approach, profile it, and then only if you determine it is too slow look at doing something custom. My understanding is that a `std::bitset<30>` will only use 4 bytes of storage.

Comment: Nice Timothy, maybe you can help with [XOR bitset when 2D bitset is stored as 1D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787731/xor-bitset-when-2d-bitset-is-stored-as-1d).